# What does "Anglo" mean here

Tags: meaning-in-context

What doe ***anglo*** mean here

> Having said that, there is something which, to my absolute amazement, Obama's election did achieve: the removal of (most, but not all) Neocons from (most, but not all) key positions of power and a re-orientation of (most, but not all) of US foreign policy in a more traditional "USA first" line, usually supported by the "**old Anglo**" interests.  Sure, the Neocons are still firmly in control of Congress and the US corporate media, but the Executive Branch is, at least for the time being, back under Anglo control (this is, of course, a generalization: Dick Cheney was neither Jewish nor Zionist, while the Henry Kissinger can hardly be described as an "**Anglo**").  And even though Bibi Netanyahu got more standing ovations in Congress (29) than any US President, the attack on Iran he wanted so badly did not happen.  Instead,  Hillary and Petraeus got kicked out, and Chuck Hagel and John Kerry got in.  That is hardly "change we can believe in", but at least this shows that the Likud is not controlling the White House any more.

If you want you can read further context here http://www.informationclearinghouse.info/article36509.htm
under the subtitle *In comes Barak Obama - "change we can believe in!"*

Answer (score 2):

So, you're not going to find this exact definition in a dictionary, because this website is a heavily political source, which means it's likely to use certain words almost as a kind of code or shorthand that would not necessarily be obvious to most speakers.

As a combining form, "Anglo" means "English" (as in "Anglo-French Relations" which would mean relations between Great Britain/England and France). This is derived from "Anglo-Saxon," the term used to describe the ethnicity of the main English population, who settled England from the northern German/Danish coastal areas in the medieval period. This usage is not racist, it's just the adjective form of "English."

In modern American usage--well, actually most people don't use this word, it's not really politically correct/appropriate any more. "Anglo" is a kind of dated term to refer to what the speaker thinks of as "white people"--a [person of northern/western European descent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anglo?s=t). Like a lot of outdated ethnic terms, it can be a little poorly defined; many people might interpret it to include people of French, Dutch, Swiss, etc. ancestry, not just English. But in the context of American politics, you can interpret it as distinct from other European ethnicities, particularly southern and eastern European ones, as well as from non-white races.

In this particular context, the author is using "Anglo" to refer to the "traditional American population", i.e. immigrants in the first big wave of European migration to the United States, prior to the 1800s. He's doing this to draw a distinction between those people (assumed to be Christians) and Jews. This is seriously anti-Semitic in context, because the rest of the article seems to make repeated references to conspiracy theories of a secret network of Jewish people that run the world behind the scenes. Basically the part you quoted is saying that Barack Obama's election changed the political order to put political control into the hands of people [the author](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crackpot) does not regard as part of a Jewish conspiracy.

I don't want to spend too much more time analyzing an article that I personally find distasteful, but to truly understand this article you will need a lot of additional knowledge about American ethnic and racial divisions, and trends in American politics, political ideology, and intellectual history in the last forty years or so.